# Vertically center an image within an AdminLte content-wrapper div

Tags: html, css, laravel, bootstrap-4

I am using an AdminLte template, which I use as a layout. In the part where I am going to put the content it is like this:

```
        <div class="content-wrapper">
            <section class="content">
                    @yield('content')
            </section>
            <!-- /.content -->
        </div>
```

In the view where I have the content to display I have:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div>
        <img class="mx-auto my-auto d-block" src="{{ asset('dist/img/logo.png')}}" alt="logo" style="opacity: .2">
    </div>
@endsection
```

When executing, the image of the logo appears centered horizontally, but vertically it appears attached to the upper margin. I've tried various shapes, but can't get it to center vertically. I can't figure out how to fix it. I will appreciate a help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Bootstrap 4, you can use .d-flex .align-items-center
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/#align-items

The result like this:

```
<div class="content d-flex align-items-stretch bg-info w-100">

    <div class="d-flex bg-info w-100">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center w-100">
            <img class="w-100" src="https://via.placeholder.com/800x200">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here full demo
https://jsfiddle.net/herupurwito/8oq67jcr/3/

Comment: Thank you very much sir, your contribution solved the problem. Have a nice day.